# Google Admob ads only show from playstore

Tags: android, admob

1. I am using play-service-ads version 20.5.0
2. I signed app-release.aab and app-release.apk
3. I upload .aab to playstore and its showing ads fine.
4. I also download my app from apkpure and its also showing ads.

The problem is when I install app-release.apk, it doesn't show ads!
Is it normal or what do I need to show ads on apk file?
Because I want to share the apk file too.

Answer (score 1):

Google Admob never allows ads in APK which is never downloaded from Playstore.
If you do this Admob will count this behavior as Invalid traffic and your ads will be limited.

You see Admob always says store key in `examplewebsite.com/apps-ads.txt` it checks the invalid traffics. if you install the app from Playstore it will allow the ads otherwise ads will be limited.

Sometimes in my case testing ads also didn't show on debugging APK then I use a simple technique to solve this problem I always change the package name and test my ads on debugging APK. Finally, when I want to release the signed bundle I put the original package name in the app and published it. Also, register your testing device to Google Admob for testing purposes.